# Windows 10: How to set IP address using netsh but using MAC address?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10

So I have a dual port gigabit Ethernet card and I want to setup their IPs via a batch script.

I have used this and it works at the time I first wrote it.

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet" static 192.168.2.2 255.255.255.0
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet 2" static 192.168.3.2 255.255.255.0
```

But the problem is when I reinstalled Windows. Windows has swapped them so the IPs got swapped as well.

I am hoping to can help me with another script/command where I can use MAC address instead of "interface name" since this name can be swapped.

Thanks

Comment: So you should rename the adaptors.  Rename the first adaptor to something other then "Ethernet" allowing you to rename "Ethernet 2" to "Ethernet" then rename the first adaptor that you renamed to "Ethernet 2"

Comment: You would have to go to a Powershell script in order to do it by MAC address